# Evaluation of the XPath resulted in an error

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm trying to get the **MedicalResults** tag in the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <jsonObject>
         <atenciones>
            <center>
               <n1>13601</n1>
               <extra>
                  <type_id>NI</type_id>
               </extra>
            </center>
            <Remission>
               <type>2</type>
               <Diagnose>
                  <illness>xxx</illness>
               </Diagnose>
               <MedicalResults>
                  <id_auth>123</id_auth>
                  <AdditionalData>
                     <quantity>20</quantity>
                  </AdditionalData>
               </MedicalResults>
            </Remission>
         </atenciones>
      </jsonObject>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have an iterator inside a sequence with the following code (WSO2EI v6.4.0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="AtencionTransformacionInSequence">
       <log>
          <property name="Sequence" value="Starting sequence" />
       </log>
       <payloadFactory media-type="json">
          <format>{"atenciones":$1}</format>
          <args>
             <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('jsonAtenciones')" literal="false" />
          </args>
       </payloadFactory>
       <!-- issue starts here -->
<iterate xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" continueParent="true" expression="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/jsonObject/atenciones/Remission/MedicalResults" sequential="true">
<!-- issue ends -->
          <target>
             <sequence>
                <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                   <format>{"Remission": $1}</format>
                   <args>
                      <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/atenciones" literal="false" />
                   </args>
                </payloadFactory>
                <log>
                   <property name="Saving data" value="OK" />
                </log>
                <send receive="AtencionTransformacionOutSequence" />
             </sequence>
          </target>
       </iterate>
       <sequence key="ProgressionInSequence" />
       <respond />
    </sequence>
```

[image: Screen capture from WSO2EI]
I have tried the following instructions but the log keeps showing **Evaluation of the XPath expression resulted in an error**

- $body/jsonObject/atenciones/Remission/MedicalResults
- json-eval($.jsonObject.atenciones.Remission/MedicalResults)
- //ns:jsonObject/ns:atenciones/ns:Remission/ns:MedicalResults

But none of it has worked, how can i solve the issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you to use WSO2 Integration Studio, You can evaluate XPaths easily.

Comment: Can you explain your use case here

Comment: Could you please explain what for do you try to use iterator here? As I can see, after payloadFactory medator, message context will contain only json object and you can iterate through json array, not object.

Comment: sorry for the late, the iterator is used because this is part of a web services composition,  some of the backend web services aren't able to process arrays, let's say, the medical prescription web service only accepts one prescription, meanwhile the composition will receive multiple data, it has to be transformed so we can get various database rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<log level="full"/>` mediator above the iterate mediator so that it will print the content of the message context at that point. Please check the wso2carbon.log to verify whether the content that you try to obtain with the XPath expression is present in the message context.

Comment: sorry for the late and thank you for your answer, at this moment the provider is validating the incident, apparently is related to the wso2 version, the real code is working in a local enironment with E.I. v6.5 but not in v6.4.